# Get Specific Objects Inside An Array of Dictionaries in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries and I want to get the values of the array that contains the key I'm searching.

For example I have this array called `locationArray`:

```
(
    {
    id = 1,
    info = 
        {
        name = "Person1";
        address = "Chicago";
        };
    };
    id = 2,
    info = 
        {
        name = "Person2";
        address = "Chicago";
        };
    };
    id = 3,
    info = 
        {
        name = "Person3";
        address = "New York";
        };
    };
);
```

and I want to get an array of all persons with address at Chicago. The result (`chicagoArray`)would be like this:

```
(
    {
    id = 1,
    info = 
        {
        name = "Person1";
        address = "Chicago";
        };
    };
    id = 2,
    info = 
        {
        name = "Person2";
        address = "Chicago";
        };
    };
);
```

I did this loop but I don't know what to make of my resultArray:

```
for (id result in locationArray)
{
     if ([[result valueForKeyPath@"info.address"] isEqualToString:@"Chicago"])
     {
         // What to do inside the resultArray?
         // NSArray *resultArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@""];
     }
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Is that an assignment for us?

Comment: Nope. I just want to know the right way of searching inside the array of dictionaries and creating a new array of the results of that search.

Comment: @jaytrixz just an FYI: There is not a _the_ right way to search an array, so your question is not really a good fit here. Try your own code and if it gives you any problems, then you have something that can be addressed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* entries= [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary* dict in array)
{
    NSDictionary* innerDict= dict[@"info"];
    if([innerDict[@"address"] isEqualToString: @"Chicago"])
    {
        [entries addObject: dict];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your sample code and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your array contains a `NSDictionary`.

You can iterate through and check for the condition, if satisfies then add that object to new array.